# Jest is unable to detect the mock function call

Tags: javascript, express, jestjs

I'm writing the unit tests for one on the controller in the Express app. I'm mocking `res.send` method and expect it to be called when user passes the valid data like this:

```js
describe('>> CONTROLLERS -- Exercise -- deleteExercise', () => {
  let res

  beforeEach(() => {
    res = {
      send : jest.fn()
    }
  });

  it('sends error as response if id was not passed', () => {
    const req = {
      body : {}
    }
    deleteExercise(req, res)

    expect(res.send).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
      error : 'please pass id field to delete the exercise.'
    })
  })

  it('calls the deleteExercise class method if the id was passed', () => {
    const req = {
      body : {
        id : 1234
      }
    }

    deleteExercise(req, res)

    expect(Exercise.deleteExercise).toHaveBeenCalledWith(1234)
    expect(res.send).toHaveBeenCalled()
    // expect(res.send).toHaveBeenCalledWith(mockData)
  })
})
```

The first test runs fine, but the second is not. I've added consoles to check if the `res.send` was called or not, in code it's being called, but Jest fails for `expect(res.send).toHaveBeenCalled()` test. Could you please help me with what I'm missing here...

Comment: What does the deleteExercise() function look like?

Comment: @ArpanKc it calls the DB and makes the delete call. And returns the status `okay`. but I've mocked it to return an empty object for now.

Comment: give us the information about the error message.

Comment: @SubratoPatnaik the test is failing. the error says function wasn't called.

Comment: If you provide the console.log error message would be great for my learning and understanding. And I am not the one who downvoted this question

Answer (score -1):

After taking some time into debugging, I think you also need to provide status to your mock response.

```
mockResponse = {
   send : jest.fn()
   status: jest.fn(() => mockResponse),
}
```

```
describe('>> CONTROLLERS -- Exercise -- deleteExercise', () => {
  let mockResponse

  beforeEach(() => {
    mockResponse = {
      send : jest.fn()
      status: jest.fn(() => mockResponse),
    }
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    jest.clearAllMocks();
  });

  it('sends error as response if id was not passed', () => {
    const mockRequest = {
      body : {}
    }
    deleteExercise(mockRequest, mockResponse)

    expect(mockResponse.send).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
      error : 'please pass id field to delete the exercise.'
    })
  })


  it('calls the deleteExercise class method if the id was passed', () => {
    const mockRequest = {
      body : {
        id : 1234
      }
    }

   deleteExercise(mockRequest, mockResponse)
 // deleteExercise is called with req, res arguments

    expect(Exercise.deleteExercise).toHaveBeenCalled()
    expect(Exercise.deleteExercise).toHaveBeenCalledWith(mockRequest, mockResponse) 
    expect(Exercise.deleteExercise).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
    expect(mockResponse.send).toHaveBeenCalled()
    expect(mockResponse.send).toHaveBeenCalledWith(1234)
    expect(mockResponse.send).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)

  })
})
```

`deleteExercise` function is called with `res` and `req`, not with the `id`.
First, check deleteExercise is called or not, then check whether the same function is called with arguments. Then check later how many times the function is called.

One more thing, clear all the mocks after each test case.

```
afterEach(() => {
    jest.clearAllMocks();
});
```